# How do I project sub elements in a Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I'm trying to pull specific sub elements from a Mongo database. I've used a sample set of data containing  all the books and verses in the Bible. I need to query and display an individual verse.

The data looks like this:

```
{"book": "1 Chronicles",
    "chapters": [
           {"chapter": "1", 
                 "verses": [
                     {"verse": "1", "text": "Adam, Sheth, Enosh,"}, 
                     {"verse": "2", "text": "Kenan, Mahalaleel, Jered,"}]},
           {"chapter": "2", 
                 "verses": [
                    {"verse": "1", "text": "These are the sons of Israel; Reuben, Simeon, Levi,"}, 
                    {"verse": "2", "text": "Dan, Joseph, and Benjamin, Naphtali, Gad, and Asher."}]}, 
           {"chapter": "3", 
                  "verses": [
                    {"verse": "1", "text":  “etc etc…..”}]}]
             }
```

I've tried many query variations but nothing seems to work. Here are two I've tried:

```
Db.bible.find({“book”:”1 Chronicles”,”chapters.chapter”:”1”,”verses.verse”:”1”}).pretty()

Db.bible.find({“book”:”1 Chronicles”,”chapters”:[“chapter”:”1”, “verses”:[“verse”:”1”]]})
```

I have a background in MySQL, so maybe I'm just looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: See these [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/projection/).

Answer (score 0):

This is "array filtering" on more than a single match which the basic projection capabilities of .find() cannot do.

You can use [MongoDB aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to achieve your use case.

MongoDB’s aggregation framework is modeled on the concept of data processing pipelines. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into an aggregated result.

You can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in an aggregation pipeline to get your end result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "book": "1 Chronicles"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "chapters": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$chapters",
              "as": "chapters",
              "in": {
                "chapter": "$$chapters.chapter",
                "verses": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$chapters.verses",
                    "as": "verses",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$verses.verse",
                        "1"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "chapters",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$chapters.chapter",
              "1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H4KBMwrdCXs)